# Is there a possibility to add the Wiki webpart on the webpart page?

Tags: web-part, content-editor-web-part, web-part-page

We are customizing the webpart pages in SharePoint 2010, I have updated the page layout as per the requirement(i.e, to display the left navigation, layout of the main content placeholder) however would like to display the predefined text & images in the header & footer sections.

Is there a possibility to directly add the Wiki webpart on the webpart page?

Steps followed:

1. Replaced the file *"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\1033\STS\DOCTEMP\SMARTPGS\spstd1.aspx"* **with** *"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\DocumentTemplates\wkpstd.aspx"*
2. updated the code, see paste http://pastebin.com/unP0hTzj

It does not seem to work as expected..

Comment: You code seems to be poorly formatted with missing some tags so I moved it to Pastebin instead.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to 14 hive files is something **NOT Recommended** by Microsoft! - You should avoid doing it

To pre-fetch your content, you should use some lists to store data and DataViewer webparts for displays. OOTB WebPart can be easily added to the Page Layouts with XML or SharePoint APIs

Comment: Is that mean, we may not be able to add the wiki webpart on the webpartpage template also can not add the other webparts into the wiki template(14hive)...sure, I will make sure that it will be properly packaged and deployed...

Comment: I stumpled upon this in 2007 and solved by creating a custom site definition http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2012/07/05/9443563.aspx. I'm not sure if we can pull it off in 2010 though.

Comment: do we have the complete solution? means the package...so that I can use it as a base..